# Illustrator rectangle resize issue

Tags: adobe-illustrator, resize, anchor-point

So I have this strange Illustrator issue and I'm not sure if it's a bug or a "feature"...

I'm using the latest version of Illustrator CC.

I have rather thin grey rectangle:

[image: A grey rectangle]

If a zoom in and want to resize the rectangle (using the Selection tool) and make it taller I just pull the handle down like this:

[image: A grey rectangle]

and it works as it should. But if I zoom out and try to do the same thing this happens:

[image: A grey rectangle]

The upper part of the rectangle no longer stay where it should but moves down as I pull down the handle.

Is there any way to change this?

Oh, a bonus question! Why are the anchor points in my rectangles in Illustrator sometimes filled (left) and sometimes not (right)?

[image: Filled and non filled anchor points]

Comment: I had the same problem. But I have not observed it in CC 14 yet. Maybe they fixed it. What version are you working on? Does it also happen when Smart Guides are switched off? To me it only happened when using the regular Selection Tool. Try avoiding it by using the Free Transform Tool, the Direct Selection Tool and the Transform Panel whenever possible.

Comment: I'm using the latest version of CC. I tried switching off the Smart Guides and use the Free Transform tool but neither made any difference.

Comment: If there are no other answers you should call Adobe Support. Maybe they will ask you to reset Illustrator to the factory defaults or reinstall it. You could do that first to speed up things. Please let us know what they told you.

Answer (score 1):

In some zoom levels, especially less than 100%, if the width/height of an object is small then the scale function with its bounding box will be wrong.

To solve it, just zoom in your working view to make the bounding box match the object's actual path and the scaling will be accurate.

Alternatively, use the `Transform` panel to set the anchor point of the object.